# Generate SQL for multiple indexes with sqldeveloper

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-indexes

I have recently exported an Oracle database to a new environment.  Unfortunately, many of the indexes failed to create.  I would like to know if there is a way to generate sql for a variety of these.

For example, I know if you select a table and click the "SQL" tab on the list across the top, it will generate the sql output automatically.  (See screenshot) However, I need to do this for most, if not all, the entire database.  It's the indexes I'm most interested in.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uZAd.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using dbms_metadata on the source database, you can generate the DDL statements for all indexes you're interested in:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('INDEX', index_name) from user_indexes
```

This will give you the DDL statements for all indexes of the currently connected user; if you want indexes for all users, use all_indexes / dba_indexes instead (the latter requires special privileges).

Comment: This is perfect, thanks.  I can probably add this a a custom extension or something too! :)